# Git changes not applied on overleaf

Tags: git, github

I am experiencing a strange problem with Overleaf today.  Since this morning I made several changes to one of my projects and I can see them fine when I view the project online.  However, if I download/clone the project locally or push it to github, none of the changes are being reflected.  All I see is changes applied about a month ago.  Time stamps on changed files are all incorrect.  In fact for most of my files, I see a future timestamp, which I presume is because the server is in the UK and I am in the US.

There doesn't appear to be a way to quickly get help from overleaf so I am posting here in the hope that this is a git issue of some kind and a resolution could be found here.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try again and:

- clone the overleaf project, [using its internal link](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/195-new-collaborate-online-and-offline-with-overleaf-and-git-beta) from its share link:

> In this case, the project link is https://www.overleaf.com/2029559gkypzx, so its git link is https://git.overleaf.com/2029559gkypzx.

- Make sure your are on the master branch with git status
- Change a file, add, commit and push

See if the issue persists.